# Closed curves question

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, integration

Can you give me some help on the following problem?

Given two closed curves $\alpha, \beta : \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ we define $\phi_{\alpha \beta}: I^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ as $\phi_{\alpha \beta} (s, t) = \alpha(s) - \beta (t)$.

Now, let $F, G: I^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ be in class $C^1$. We define $F_s(t) = F(s, t)$ and $G_s(t) = G(s, t)$ for all $s \in [0, 1]$. Assuming that, for all $s \in [0, 1]$, $F_s$ and $G_s$ do not intersect each other. Prove that 
$\int_{\phi_{F_0 G_0}}d\omega = \int_{\phi_{F_1 G_1}}d\omega$ holds for any differential $1$-form $\omega$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{(0, 0, 0)\}$.

I'm guessing that both integrals are equal to $0$, but I'm having trouble proving it since $\alpha$ is not defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$.